# Append to register inside a global command

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I have a file whose content could be like the following:

```
foo1
bar1
foo2
bar2
bar3
```

I want to delete from the file all the lines matching the pattern `^foo` and put them altogether somewhere else, possibly in a different file, using the `p` command.

I've tried using the command `:g/^foo/"Ad` supposing each deleted line would be appended to the register `a`. However the command doesn't delete anything nor appends anything to the register `a`.

What's wrong with the command I used? Store/append to register is not supposed to work inside a `global` command?

There are other commands I can use to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can to use the `:normal` command along with your usage of `:global`.

```
:g/^foo/norm "Add
```

Or you can use `:delete` ex command:

```
:g/^foo/d A
```

For more help see:

```
:h :d
:h :norm
```